# Compile LLVM-IR into JS with Emscripten?

Tags: javascript, llvm, llvm-ir, emscripten

So I know that emscripten compiles C/C++ -> LLVM-IR -> JS. Is there a way to compile LLVM-IR to JS directly?

I wrote the following function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void) {
  int a = 4;
  int b = 5;
  int c = a + b;
  printf("Returned: %d\n", c);
  return 0; 
}
```

And I verified that I can compile it to JS using `emcc test.c -o test`, which generated a working JS file.

Then I tried getting the llvm-ir (using `clang -S -emit-llvm test.c`), which produces what appears to be a valid llvm-ir file. But when I try to compile that to JS (per `emcc test.ll`) I get: `error: expected top-level entity`.

Anyone seen that error before? Know how I can get around it?

Thanks,

Comment: Additionally, if I feed it to clang (using `clang test.ll`) it compiles to a working file...

Comment: Okay, if you remove the `source_filename = "test.c"` (line 2 of the `test.ll` file), then it works -- so this must be an intentional check, is there a way to suppress this?